# arrange k identical robots in 15 chairs, with limitations

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I ran into this question, want to challenge you.

in how many ways can you arrange a number of identical robots on $15$ chairs?

limitations:
1) $2$ robots cannot sit next to each other.
2) each empty chair has at least one neighbour with a robot.

what i got so far: i know that it has something to do with $\sum_{5}^{8}$ because the minimum amount of robots is $5$ and maximum is $8$.

i'm not sure how to proceed from here though.

Thank you very much in advance,

Yaron

Comment: Are the chairs in a circle?  What does "next to" mean?

Comment: the chairs are in a row. are chair i "next to" a chair if he is beside him in the row.

Comment: I wonder what's the problem with the people who invent these math problems with... real life situations. Sitting robots in chairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $xRExRExRExRExRx$.  The $R$'s stand for robots, the $E$'s stand for empty chairs.  All the $x$'s can be zero or one empty chairs.   However there are 15 chairs altogether, so in fact each $x$ must be one empty chair.

Consider now one more robot.  $xRExRExRExRExRExRx$.  We have six robots and five empty chairs accounted for, of 15 chairs.  That means there are four empty chairs to distribute among the seven possible $x$'s, which can be done in ${7\choose 4}$ ways.

I leave the cases of 7 or 8 robots for you to consider.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, i just have one question.
what about the internal arrangements? f.e, when i have 6 robots, we checked for $xRExRExRExRExRx$ and we found the answer $\binom{7}{4}$, but what about $xRxERxERxERxERx$, which is the exact mirror? do we need to check for it too?

Comment: Try calculating several examples and see; $Ex$ is a placeholder for 1 or 2 empty chairs, and so is $xE$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Think about a recurrence.  Let $R(n)$ be then number of acceptable strings of length $n$ ending in $R, E(n)$ be the number of acceptable strings of length $n$ ending in $RE$, and $EE(n)$ the number of acceptable strings of length $n$ ending in $EE$.  We have $R(1)=1, E(1)=0, EE(0)=0, R(n)=EE(n-1)+E(n-1), E(n)=R(n-1), EE(n)=E(n-1)$  Can you see why?
For small $n$, a spreadsheet makes this easy.  For larger $n$, making a matrix and diagonalizing will solve it.

Comment: thanks, i just have one question:
why isn't it: $R(n)=EE(n-1)+E(n-1)+R(n-1)$? why did you ignore the option that the n-1 string ends with R?
in addition, why is $EE(n)=E(n-1)$? if there is an $E$ in the end of the $n-1$ string, then, i have to put an $R$ in the end, not an $E$.

thanks, yaron.

Comment: @user76508:  In the $R$ recurrence, we can't add another $R$ to a string that ends in $R$.  In the EE recurrence, I was thinking you can put a second empty because there is an $R$ just before the final $E$, but you are right that there is a termination problem here.  You can put a second $E$ as long as there is another $R$ to come.  The relation given is fine until the final step, but at the end $EE(n)=0$

Comment: so what do i do in this situation? if there's a difference between the last step and the steps before, can we still use recurrence?

Comment: @user76508:  You can.  I would use the recurrence as given, then note that the final answer is $R(n)+E(n)$.  In essence $EE(n)$ is the number of not yet bad strings that end in EE.

Comment: i'll try it. thank you very much.